# why doesn't node-fetch work on this site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am trying to scrape the site **"`https://shmoti.com`"** . But unfortunately node-fetch's `fetch` method is not at all getting the response. It works fine for other websites.

Here is my code

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
fetch('https://shmoti.com', options = {headers : {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}}).then(res=>res.text()).then(res=>console.log(res))
```

The first promise which resolves the response object is pending all the time.

I have even tried having a User-Agent . I have set a timeout of 60 seconds . 
I can successfully scrape this site using `scrapy` library in python but with `fetch` method , it always times out.

Why is this happening ? How can I fix this ?

I can ping the website and open it in my browser too , but only the fetching from node is not working.

Comment: `not at all getting the response` - so, nothing at all? partial response? any errors? do you have error handling in your invisible code to indicate what the problem may be?

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: @Natesh, I tried it here, it works but.
https://runkit.com/shankarshastri/node-fetchtest

Comment: @ShankarShastri the same code doesn't work when I run it from my machine . Is it possible that the site has blocked me ? If so how can i get around it ?

Comment: Can you ping the website?

Comment: you can change your ip or access via proxy, I can't say much more because I never tried any of those...

Comment: Yes I can ping @ShankarShastri

Comment: Then your IP is not blocked @Nateshbhat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111411/node-fetch-only-returning-promise-pending

Comment: Then what mechanism might they be using ? I can access their site from chrome normally but the fetch method doesn't work ... :/  My same code works for other websites but not this

Comment: `I have even tried having a User-Agent` show this code

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated code now .see

Comment: perhaps you should make the user agent look like an actual real browser

Comment: Anyway, this exact example works for me, with bad user-agent and everything. (node 8.11.3, node-fetch@2.1.2)

Comment: @ShankarShastri - pinging isn't the same as requesting a page on port 443 :p

Comment: @ippi - you are right - the page "scrapes" even without a user-agent - perhaps `shmoti` has some anti-scraping logic, or problem exists between keyboard and chair

Comment: What mechanism might that be? Any idea?

Comment: @Nateshbhat - one that prevents people from *borrowing* resources that do not belong to them

Comment: The scraping works fine when I use scrapy in python without any proxy

Comment: well, perhaps you're doing something else wrong ... nobody else is having a problem scraping that website using your code - so, the problem is not with the code you've shown

Comment: thats the thing im not able to figure out , it was working fine a few days back . After that they changed thier site and renewed it . After that its not working in nodejs. :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had a similar issue. `node-fetch` worked on github, but not on another site I was wanting to access. `wget` worked fine, however. Using `netcat`, I analyzed the differences in headers between the fetch request vs wget's request. The difference was that fetch would request with the connection=close while wget would request with connection=keep-alive. Adding this to my fetch header got the job done.

```
{
  "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709657) for more info on using netcat. Made it super easy to debug and I didn't previously know about this tool.